# How do I escape apostrophes within an awk statement?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, awk

I'm using Ubuntu Linux with the bash shell.  How do I escape apostrophes within an awk statement?  I want to output some SQL, after extracting data from a file using awk, so I have:

```
awk -F',' '{print "SELECT * from user where id = '"$2"';"}' myfile.csv
```

But this prints out only:

```
SELECT * from user where id = ;
```

If I modify the above to

```
awk -F',' '{print "SELECT * from user where id = "$2";"}' myfile.csv
```

then I get a statement like

```
SELECT * from user where id = cf915247dfcf47b6814b5350e5cbdfd8;
```

but there are no single quotes around the id, which I need.

Comment: So you want to have `cf915247dfcf47b6814b5350e5cbdfd8` single-quoted ? like `'cf915247dfcf47b6814b5350e5cbdfd8'` ?

Comment: Yes you said it exactly right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to approach this in two ways:

1. Pass single quote via variable:

   ```
   awk -v sq="'" -F',' '{print "SELECT * from user where id = "sq$2sq";"}' myfile.csv
   ```
2. Make use of hex value of the single quote in printf statement:

   ```
   awk -F',' '{printf "SELECT * from user where id = %c%s%c;\n",0x27,$2,0x27}' myfile.csv
   ```

Comment: I like that.  Never thought about setting a single quote variable.  +1

Answer (score 2):

#### You can [just use `\47`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Read-Terminal) (or `\047`) in your string, which `awk` takes to mean `'`.

```
awk -F, '{print "SELECT * from user where id = \47" $2 "\47;"}' myfile.csv
```

That's sort of inelegant ("What's the repeated [magic value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) '47' doing?!") but the syntax is clean and this technique for making a single quote is [pretty](http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote) [well](https://minhhh.github.io/posts/awk-tutorial#quote-and-quoting) [known](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/44875-inserting-apostrophe-into-awk-output.html).

`awk` is what treats `\47` specially, not your shell. In `'` `'`-quoted strings, Bourne-style shells like Bash [do not perform *any* expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes). C Shells like `tcsh` do, but they don't expand `\47` and this still works.

**You may prefer to use `\047` instead of `\47`.** They both work, unless `\47` is followed immediately by an octal digit (0-7), in which case you must use `\047` to avoid indicating the wrong character. Note that, unlike in some languages, the `47` in `\47` is octal even without the leading `0`; see below.

#### What does `\47` mean? Why does this use `\47` when [that way](https://askubuntu.com/a/875404/22949) uses `0x27`?

This is because two sixteens make four eights.

- `\47` is an [*octal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) character sequence, so it's 4×8 + 7×1 = 39.
- `0x27` is a [*hexadecimal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numeric literal, so it's 2×16 + 7×1 = 39.
  Then `printf`'s `%c` specifier formats it as a character.

Checking with `python -c 'print int("47", 8), int("27", 16)'` gives `39 39`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is going to look crazy, but here you go:

```
awk -F',' '{print "SELECT * from user where id = '"'"'" $2 "'"'"'" ";"}' myfile.csv

SELECT * from user where id = 'cf915247dfcf47b6814b5350e5cbdfd8';
```

Hope this helps!